# Flutter Couldn't find correct Provider<Type> above widget x

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

[image]

I am using the provider state management technique.

In Widget E if I try to access the value of Provider A, B, C it is available
But At level 2, I have one future provider, When I try to access the value of this provider in widget E it gives an exception that 
- Couldn't find the correct Provider above widget E.

What could be the possible issues?
The image depicts the hierarchy in which the widgets are called while execution.

Comment: use provider one level up and it will work